# Http post returns error 400 bad request asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

Http post returns error 400 bad request, this is my code, can you see where I'm going wrong? I'm guessing it's something to do with the url?

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        data["var1"] = source1;
        data["var2"] = source2;
        data["var3"] = source3;


    // HTTP post and redirect the values
    string str2 = string.Empty;

    System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (string str3 in data.AllKeys)
    {
        builder.Append(str2);
        builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str3));
        builder.Append("=");
        builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data[str3]));
        str2 = "&";
    }

    //Make a request
    string path = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    string url = path + Target + builder;
    url = "http://localhost:1541/test/var1=SELEZIONA&var2=SELEZIONA&var3=SELEZIONA";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    //Put the post data into the request
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    reqStream.Close();

    //Get response
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
```

I've put the actual url content in the url variable to show what it is currently trying to send.

Comment: Stupid question, is the site running and the app pools started?

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking a questionmark in the URL to separate the querystring. I guess that could cause this kind of error. Try this instead:

```
url = "http://localhost:1541/test/?var1=SELEZIONA&var2=SELEZIONA&var3=SELEZIONA";
```

Comment: ah of course, missed that. Is the page supposed to redirect to the target after running the http post? it does'nt seem to do anything yet.

Comment: @PeteTheGreek Well, you tell me what it is supposed to do. This code simply reads the response of the request. What you do next is up you.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head round posting a form from code behind to another page, is this code to send http data or to recieve? thanks, pete.

Comment: @PeteTheGreek Your code seems to make an HTTP POST request and then then read the server response. If that is what you mean?